# Prove the inequality $\|x\|_p \le N^{1 - 1/q}\|x\|_q$.

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, lp-spaces

In my functional analysis course, we define
$$\|x\|_p = \left(\sum_{k = 1}^N |x_i|^p\right)^{1/p}$$
for $x \in \mathbb{R}^N$ and $p \in [1, +\infty)$. Then the teacher told us that, for $p \le q$, it was obvious that
$$\|x\|_q \le \|x\|_p \le N^{1 - 1/q}\|x\|_q.$$
The first inequality is not too hard, because
$$\left|\frac{x_j}{\|x\|_q}\right|^q \le \left|\frac{x_j}{\|x\|_q}\right|^p \quad \forall j \in \{1, \ldots, N\},$$
and then, after summation $1 \le (\|x\|_p/\|x\|_q)^p$. But I don't really see how can I prove the second inequality. Any idea?

Comment: Do you know Young's inequality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that
$$
\|x\|_p^q = N^{q/p}\left(\frac 1N\sum_{k = 1}^N |x_i|^p\right)^{q/p}.
$$
Then use Jensen's inequality $\varphi\left(\sum_{k=1}^N\alpha_kt_k\right)\leqslant \sum_{k=1}^N\alpha_k\varphi\left(t_k\right)$ where $\alpha_k\geqslant 0$ and $\sum_{k=1}^N\alpha_k=1$, here with $\alpha_k=1/N$ and $\varphi(t)=t^{q/p}$.